# Cut the background to expose the layer below

Tags: css, webkit

Is there a way to cut a div background to expose the layer below?, like going from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Any bleeding edge css rule is welcome!

**UPDATE**

Ok, I've made a sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/coma/9ae7g/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Menu</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            @charset 'UTF-8';

            body {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                background: #fff url("http://colourlovers.com.s3.amazonaws.com/images/patterns/1762/1762793.png?1314797062");
            }

            a {
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            #menu {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 250px;
            }

            body.wide>#menu {
                width: 0;
            }

            #menu * {
                line-height: 1em;
            }

            #menu:after {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                width: 5px;
                height: 100%;
                border-right: 1px solid #666;
                pointer-events: none;
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 100%);
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 100%);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 100%);
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 100%);
                background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 100%);
            }

            #menu ul, #menu li {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                list-style: none;
                background-color: #fafafb;
            }

            #menu li {
                position: relative;
            }

            #menu>a {
                position: absolute;
                left: 100%;
                top: 50%;
                z-index: 1;
                display: block;
                width: 10px;
                height: 20px;
                margin: -10px 0 0 0;
                text-indent: -100em;
                overflow: hidden;
                border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
                background-color: #666;
                transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
                -moz-transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
                -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
                -o-transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
                -ms-transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
            }

            #menu>a:before {
                position: absolute;
                top: 5px;
                right: 4px;
                display: block;
                content: '';
                border-width: 5px 6px 5px 0;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
            }

            body.wide>#menu>a:before {
                right: 2px;
                border-width: 5px 0 5px 6px;
                border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
            }

            #menu>ul {
                height: 100%;
                background-color: #888;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #menu>ul span, #menu>ul a {
                display: block;
                padding: .4em;
                color: #666;
                font-weight: bold;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
            }

            #menu>ul a {
                border-top: 1px solid #fff;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #e9ecee;
            }

            #menu>ul>li>span {
                font-size: 1.25em;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #666;
                text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
                background-color: #eee;
                background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%);
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%);
                background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%);
                background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%);
                background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%);
                cursor: pointer;
                transition: background-color .4s;
                -moz-transition: background-color .4s;
                -webkit-transition: background-color .4s;
                -o-transition: background-color .4s;
                -ms-transition: background-color .4s;
            }

            #menu>ul>li>span:hover {
                background-color: #fff;
            }

            #menu>ul>li>ul {
                display: none;
            }

            #menu>ul>li.opened>ul, #menu>ul>li.current_ancestor>ul {
                display: block;
            }

            #menu>ul>li>ul>li>a {
                font-size: 1.2em;
                color: #4183c4;
                transition: background-color .4s;
                -moz-transition: background-color .4s;
                -webkit-transition: background-color .4s;
                -o-transition: background-color .4s;
                -ms-transition: background-color .4s;
            }

            #menu>ul>li>ul>li.current>a, #menu>ul>li>ul>li.current>a:hover {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #39f;
                border-color: #39f;
            }

            #menu>ul>li>ul>li.current:after {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                right: -1px;
                top: 50%;
                margin: -9px 0 0 0;
                display: block;
                border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            #menu>ul>li>ul>li>a:hover {
                background: #fff;
            }

            #menu>ul>li>ul>li:last-child {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
            }

            #menu>ul>li>ul>li[data-count]:after {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                right: 14px;
                display: block;
                content: attr(data-count);
                padding: .26em .5em;
                background-color: #fff;
                border-radius: 8px;
                font-size: 12px;
                margin: -9px 0 0 0;
                color: #777;
                border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
            }

            #section {
                height: 2000px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <div id="menu">
            <a title="cerrar o abrir el menú" href="#">toggle</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="first opened">
                    <span>Usuario</span>
                    <ul class="menu_level_1">
                        <li class="first">
                            <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="current">
                            <a href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/user/">Usuarios</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="last">
                            <a href="/discount/">Descuentos</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Artistas</span>
                    <ul class="menu_level_1">
                        <li class="first">
                            <a href="/artist/">Artistas</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="last">
                            <a href="/artists/top10">Top 10 (3)</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Obras</span>
                    <ul class="menu_level_1">
                        <li class="first">
                            <a href="/artwork/">Obras</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/artworks/destacadas">Destacadas (4)</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="last">
                            <a href="/artworks/ofertas">Ofertas (3)</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Pedidos</span>
                    <ul class="menu_level_1">
                        <li class="first last">
                            <a href="/order/">Pedidos</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Blog</span>
                    <ul class="menu_level_1">
                        <li class="first">
                            <a href="/article/">Artículos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="last">
                            <a href="/category/">Categorías</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="last">
                    <span>Newsletter</span>
                    <ul class="menu_level_1">
                        <li class="first last">
                            <a href="/newsletter/">Emails</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="section"></div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                var style = {
                    opened: 'opened',
                    wide: 'wide',
                    currentAncestor: 'current_ancestor'
                };

                var menu = $('#menu');
                var items = $('#menu>ul>li');
                var body = $('body');

                items.filter('.' + style.currentAncestor)
                .removeClass(style.currentAncestor)
                .first()
                .addClass(style.opened);

                items.children('span').click(function(event) {

                    event.preventDefault();

                    var group = $(this).parent();

                    if(!group.hasClass(style.opened)) {

                        items.filter('.' + style.opened).removeClass(style.opened);
                        group.addClass(style.opened);

                    }


                });

                menu.children('a').click(function(event) {

                    event.preventDefault();

                    body.toggleClass(style.wide);

                });

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The birdy background and the #section with a height of 2000px is just for testing by moving the content.

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Can you provide a demo or some markup?

Comment: what i'd do would probably be to have the entire right side of the menu item part of an :after pseudo element, and then give a special :after element rule for the selected item, with the image as a background.
a solution that doesn't involve images can probably be reached, but it will probably involve spitting a lot of blood.

Comment: i dont think it is possible with css3 
you have to use images for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element will be transparent if it and all of it's children are transparent (no `background-color`, no `background-image`).

To accomplish what you're asking for, here's what I'd do:

1. Avoid background styling on the container of that group of elements.
2. Do all background styling on those individual navigation elements via a single image, even if you have to clip it to get it to be flexible.
3. For the active navigation element, swap the background image to one which has the transparent indent that you want.

See this JSFiddle, forked from your code: http://jsfiddle.net/2XSd5/.  This demonstrates the approach I described: make all backgrounds transparent, and use a background image for the cut out. Here's the code that I modified:

```
#menu:after { background: none; }

#menu > ul > li > ul > li.current:after { content: none; }

#menu ul, #menu li { background-color: transparent; }

#menu > ul { background-color: transparent; }

#menu > ul > li > ul > li > a, #menu > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    background-color: white;
    }

#menu > ul > li > ul > li.current > a, #menu > ul > li > ul > li.current > a:hover {
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) right center no-repeat;
    color: grey;
    }
```

Comment: Great idea! but as Ohad Milchgrub said, it will involve spitting a lot of blood... I was hoping to find something like -webkit-canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Add Z-index to the right menu, then it works