# Css almost responsive mask

Tags: css, mask

I would like to create an element in css, like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ5DL.png
I want that the width is 100% but I want that the triangle keep his width (let's say 30px) and stay centered even on a small screen...

So I try with a polygon clip path on a css gradient, but to keep the triangle centered I had to put the values in % but as you guess the triangle didn't keep his size of 30px...

Is anyone have an idea? maybe create 2 masks, one rectangular and another with an image of a triangle, but it seems not very "clean" to me...

thx ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked for something similar some time ago ([Cut the background to expose the layer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316013/cut-the-background-to-expose-the-layer-below))

Btw, **welcome to StackOverflow** (try to show some effort next time to avoid downvotes):

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/wkt8zLt6/

```
div.foo {
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    height: 1.5em;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #99f8fd 0%,#e3ccf7 100%);
}

div.foo:before,
div.foo:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: calc(50% - .5em);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: .5em;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}

div.foo:before {
    left: 0;
}

div.foo:after {
    right: 0;
}

div.foo > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -.5em;
    border: .5em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, but in fact it's not exactly what I would like to do, because in you example after & before element are not transparents, and the background of the site will be an image.

but thanks to your answer, I found something which perfectly fit to my problem, I slice my shape in 3 parts :
http://jsfiddle.net/viv54/g6r3bo51/

```
#foo{
    margin:40px 0 0;
    font-size: 50px;
}
#beforeMiddle, #afterMiddle{
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(50% - .8em);
    height: 10px;
}
#beforeMiddle{
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #b7f5fa 0%,#cae2f8 100%);
}
#middle {
    width: 1.6em;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -.8em;
    height: 10px;
    background: #cae2f8;
    position: absolute;
}
#middle:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: .8em solid transparent;
    border-right: .8em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #cae2f8;
}
#afterMiddle{
    right: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #cae2f8 0%,#decff6 100%);
}
```

thx :)

Comment: Hummm... in my example after and before pseudo elements can be however transparent you would like and you can set the image  you like too...

Comment: I don't understand how... if you set before & after in transparent it will show the background of div.foo, isn't it?

Here is the result I would like :
[link]http://jsfiddle.net/viv54/35ryfx41/

I don't see how to set your solution to have this result, but I'm sincerely interested to learn how. thx